# Failed binding to authentication address * port 1812 as server freeradius: Address already in use

Tags: freeradius

When I type the following command on my Ubuntu 16.04: **sudo freeradius -X**
I've got the message:

```
Failed binding to authentication address * port 1812 as server eduroam: Address already in use
```

I've read previous topics related to that issue and their problem were that freeradius service had been running already. But in my case it's true. Here is output of the command: **sudo ps aux | grep freeradius**:

```
tnur      1349  0.0  0.0  12948   932 pts/0    S+   09:44   0:00 grep --color=auto freeradius
```

There is no running freeradius service!
What could be the problem in my case?

Comment: Try `sudo lsof -i tcp:1812`.  That should tell you what process is listening on that port.

Comment: ps ax | grep radiusd

Comment: `netstat -nalp | fgrep 1812` (as root) should also tell you what uses port 1812. Since it's a high port, it could be in use by anything (could also be allocated as an ephemeral client port).

Comment: I did both commands - nothing!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got two listen sections bound to the same port.  Remove all symlinks from `freeradius/sites-enabled` and add them back one by one until you find the conflicting listener.

My guess is you changed the `inner-tunnel` virtual server to listen on port `1812`.  Don't do that, the listener in this virtual server is only so you can send test packets.  In normal operations requests are proxied to that virtual internally.

Answer (score 0):

As per Arrans answer, however for those looking at the same issue: extend garethTheReds comment and try the following as well (to catch any services running on UDP rather than TCP port):

sudo lsof -i udp:1812

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).